# What is the term for non-size limited stream function?

Tags: delphi, stream, terminology, delphi-xe

As far as I can understand streams are of a fixed size, whether they are memory or file streams. Is there a term for an open ended stream like a serial port or a network socket connection?

I'm working in Delphi XE. I've looked at classes that are decended from TStream. I would like to make an interface to a general class that would apply to a serial port, network socket, keyboard entry or simulated data. These would be data flow of no specifed length, containing packets of usable data.

I'm at a loss for the proper search term. Maybe the right term is a socket, but that seems to be a more specific network term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stream, pipeline, socket, file, whatever... they are all similar, in the following:

- They are initialized (opened) then destroyed (closed);
- You have an handle (instance) over this structure;
- You use Read and Write methods which may retrieve less content than requested (it allows unsized/infinite/abstract stream).

In the [POSIX/UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_architecture) world, for instance, "everything is a file", even a network, a setting, a cpu, a device...

In Delphi, you can perfectly inherits from a `TStream` to implement this behavior.

Even the `Seek` method does not need to handle all the cases. You can have one-way / unidirectional streams, read-only or write-only stream.

Then you can share the same code with diverse `TStream` implementations, to/from a file, a network, some memory, the keyboard, a screen, whatever... You can even nest streams, in order to add on-the-fly compression, encryption, replication...

So if you are in the Delphi world, just call it "stream", implements a `TStream`... and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

It's still a stream. You might call it a *sequential-access* stream, to differentiate it from a *random-access* stream. When implementing your `TStream` descendant, you're free to have the `Seek` method throw an exception if someone calls it to seek backward, forward, or any other disallowed usage.

Something that can be read from but not written to is a *source*, and something that can be written to but not read from is a *sink*. No fixed sizes are implied with those terms.

Comment: @Downvoter, *unidirectional* suggests that seeking is allowed, but only in one direction (probably forward). If the underlying data source doesn't support seeking, you can simulate it by implementing `Seek` such that it calls `Read` and discards whatever it reads. If you're not allowed to skip input, and you don't implement `Seek` to make it look like you are, then I don't think *unidirectional* is a good term for it.

Answer (score 0):

Listening to a port,socket or other types of communication is sometimes called a **sniffer** or a **protocol analyzer**.

To implement a general method for this is not trivial.

You would have to implement a specific abstraction layer for each type of communication.
For example, listening to a serial port without knowing the protocol format is doomed to fail.

Comment: I'm looking to make a real simple interface that makes a buffer of AnsiCharacters to available with a notification event with no regard to the data it contains. The object that receives the data will store it into another buffer and make decisions as to whether or not to notify the next level if there is acceptable data ready. [ Data Consumer ] <---- [ Raw Data Parser] <---- [Serial Data Source]

Comment: A buffer of TBytes is a better approach, since AnsiStrings should be avoided in data packets.

Comment: These would not be strings at this level. The data could be incomplete. Bytes would be better description. I was trying to convey that the data would not be Unicode.

Comment: @LU RD The `RawByteString` type is good for storing data packets. If you don't handle it as a string and don't convert it to PAnsiChar, you'll have more methods than the standard `TBytes` (e.g. concact, delete, insert), and for huge packets it may be a bit faster, since it won't fill it with zeros at initialization. It's safe to store #0 in `RawByteString`, since it will use the inlined length instead of searching for the first #0.

Comment: @Arnoud, thank you, it is good to know. I built a framework using records and TBytes with all methods I need for this kind of stuff. Similar, but same, to your TDynArray.